# Unable to connect to signal from outside class in Qt

Tags: qt, signals-slots

I have a `EmitSignal class` like this:

```
class EmitSignal : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    EmitSignal() {
        emit emittedSignal();
        qDebug() << "Signal emitted";
    }
signals:
    void emittedSignal();
};
```

And in `ConnectSlot class`, it's like this:

```
class ConnectSlot : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    ConnectSlot() {
        connect(&emitSignalObject, &EmitSignal::emittedSignal, this, &ConnectSlot::connectToSlot);
    }

    EmitSignal emitSignalObject;

public slots:
    void connectToSlot() {
        qDebug() << "Connected";
    }
};
```

As you can see, I tried to connect the `signal` and `slot`, but it seems like the `slot` is not triggered. And the only output I got is: `Signal emitted`. 
Why isn't the slot not connected and how do I do it properly?
Thanks

Comment: You connect the signal after the `emitSignalObject` is constructed, so the signal is never emmited after the connection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are emitting a signal from `EmitSignal`'s constructor. That constructor will run before the body of `ConnectSlot`'s constructor begins execution.

So the signal will be emitted before the connection is made.

You need to change your code so that connections are made before signals get fired.